# splitting multiple values in one column into multiple rows R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have a data frame which for the most part is one observation per row. However, some rows have multiple values:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
          `number`   abilities
             <dbl>       <chr>
1               51       b1261
2               57        d710
3               57 b1301; d550

structure(list(`number` = c(51, 57, 57), abilities = c("b1261", 
"d710", "b1301; d550")), .Names = c("number", "abilities"
), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

I'd like to get the following:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
          `number`   abilities
             <dbl>       <chr>
1               51       b1261
2               57        d710
3               57        d550
4               57       b1301
```

It's straight forward enough to split on the ; but I'm not sure how to easily add a new row, especially as abilities might contain more than 2 values.

This is very similar to: [R semicolon delimited a column into rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28719088/r-semicolon-delimited-a-column-into-rows) but doesn't need to remove duplicates

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There's a function `separate_rows` in `tidyr` to do just that:

```
library(tidyr)
## The ";\\s+" means that the separator is a ";" followed by one or more spaces
separate_rows(df,abilities,sep=";\\s+")
  number abilities
   <dbl>     <chr>
1     51     b1261
2     57      d710
3     57     b1301
4     57      d550
```

Comment: I think you need to trim whitespace as well, or use `sep=";\\s+"`, since otherwise the last entry will have a space at the beginning.

Comment: @Marius You're absolutely right, I hadn't spotted it. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for this, I didn't know of that feature in tidyr. I adjusted the space match to : ";\\s*" to allow for zero or more spaces

Answer (score 8):

`dplyr` is good for this as it has `unnest`:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)
df %>%
    mutate(unpacked = str_split(abilities, ";")) %>%
    unnest %>%
    mutate(abilities = str_trim(unpacked))
```

Comment: Apparently, in recent `dplyr` versions it is mandatory to  explicitely name the columns for `unnest`. So it becomes `unnest(cols = c(unpacked))`.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is `cSplit`

```
 library(splitstackshape)
 cSplit(df1, 'abilities', '; ', 'long')
 #   number abilities
 #1:     51     b1261
 #2:     57      d710
 #3:     57     b1301
 #4:     57      d550
```